# How to correctly point to files in Gulpfile.js

Tags: wordpress, sass, gulp, gulp-sass

I am trying to set up my gulpFile.js so I can use SCSS in my custom WP theme. I thought I had correctly set it up, and when I run 'gulp' in the command line, it appears to be running fine. I assume this is a simple mistake with my gulpfile. Any advice?

Thank you in advance!

[image: This is my gulpfile]
[image]

Comment: Don't show your code as an image.  It is harder for others to test or copy.  Show it as text wrapped in the code tags.

Answer (score 0):

Change your `sass` task `gulp.src` to point to your `style.scss` file where I presume all your import statements are.  Partials will **not** produce a css file, they are only meant to be imported into another file.  So

`gulp.src('./assets/sass/style.scss')`

If you had more **non-partials** in that folder it would be:

`gulp.src('./assets/sass/*.scss')`

---

and `gulp.dest(yourFolderHere)` should point to a **folder**, not a filename.  The file `style.css` will automatically be created from `style.scss`, you don't need to tell it what name to use (unless you want a different name and then you don't change the name in the gulp.dest() pipe anyway).

You just need to tell it which folder to put the resulting file into.